# Provisioning profiles and 3rd parties apps

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

Just to be sure I got everything right:

If I delete every provisioning profile on a NOT jailbroken device with xcode (window->devices->show provisioning profiles->delete all), am I 100% sure that ONLY apps downloaded from Apple App Store will run?

Edit: spelling it better.

Basically I'm asking if using xcode 6 (window->devices->show provisioning profiles) is the same as the "old" Apple Configuration Utility, which used to show you every type of profiles on a device pre-ios 8.

Thanks,
regards.

Comment: First of all, I need to reboot the device or wait a bit because of caching. Then, the app starts but exit immediately. I know that. I just wanted to be SURE to stop all 3rd parties apps (whose developers I trusted earlier, you know, iOS asking "do you trust developer xxx" etc...) doing it.

Comment: Maybe you are right, I should have spelled it better: Iphone Configuration Utility used to show you (and manage) all types of profiles (configuration or provisioning ones, ad hoc, enterprise, and so on). Now I'am asking if using xcode 6 with ios 8 devices is the same thing or, as you suggest, you cannot actually see ad hoc/enterprise ones. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I dropped my laziness and tested it myself.

Results: ALL kind of provisioning profiles (ad hoc, enterprise and not) do indeed show up in XCode in the section I highlighted above. Testflight included.

Configuration profiles do NOT show up there, but you can find them in your device settings under General->Profile. Yes, even in iOS 8 (if you have none, Profile will not be shown).

Tested with new Apple Configurator (which replaced Iphone Configuration Utility).